# Laravel Testing - How to validate each fields in JSON response

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I want to test my endpoint with valid format. For example, I have `/api/token` (POST) which will return api token.

In my case, this endpoint will return "token" string and "message" fields. Thus, I want to check if this two **fields are exist with valid format**. Currently I am using [Laravel Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation).

Example json output:

```
{
"message": "login successful",
"token": "d4zmendnd69u6h..."
}
```

Test class (ApiTokenTest.php).

```
class ApiTokenTest extends TestCase
{

    protected $validFormBody = [
        'os_type' => 'android',
        'device_id' => '0000-AAAA-CCCC-XXXX',
        'os_version' => '5.1',
        'apps_version' => '1.0',
    ];

    public function testSucessResponseFormat()
    {
        $response = $this->json('post', '/api/token', $this->validFormBody);

        $validator = Validator::make(json_decode($response->getContent(), true), [
            'token' => 'required|size:100', // token length should be 100 chars
            'message' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->assertTrue(false);
        }
        else {
            $this->assertTrue(true);
        }
    }

}
```

The issue here is the failure message is not really helps, especially if I have more than 1 fields that are not in valid format, should i assert one-by-one?. (see below `phpunit` output on failure case). What should I use in order to validate format for each fields?
Thanks in advance.

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\ApiTokenTest::testSucessResponseFormat
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not displaying anything in the terminal if there is in fact any validation errors, what you can do is a `var_dump` into the terminal if the validator fails, like so:

```
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        var_dump($validator->errors()->all());
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
    else {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. i come out with `fwrite(STDERR, print_r($validator->errors()->all(), true));` for properly showing the output